# Permission denied when writing to a open csv file opened but not with an open text file

Tags: windows, excel

I have a script that writes a list of lists to a csv file but I have noticed that when I have the file open in excel and run the process I get a *[Errno 13] Permission denied* but when it is closed or open in notepad++ I can write to the csv without an issue.

Does anyone know a way to ignore the lock that excel seems to put on a file or even close the open file.
Below is the code I'm using to write to the file (using csv module)

```
try:  
    with open(file_path_name, 'ab') as wFile:  
        writer = csv.writer(wFile, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n")  
        for csv_row in data:  
            writer.writerow(csv_row)  
except IOError as e:  
    print e
```

I'm using python 2.7, on windows 7

Comment: You don't want to ignore the lock - it's purposely there to _stop_ the excel file getting into an inconsistent state.

Comment: Excel is extremely jealous.